# When was purple PVC primer first in common use?

Tags: plumbing

Does anyone know when purple PVC primer became first in use? I cannot find the date online.

Reason: I’m in an old house and trying to find out when the plumbing was last redone, and I see the purple PVC primer being used. Was it available in the 80s? 90s? 2000s? 10s?

Any help would be great, thank you

Comment: It was in the NY plumbing code in early 2000s(2006?).

Comment: I think I remember seeing it before 2000, but I can't say how much before.

Comment: CPVC and the two-part solvent cements used with it were introduced in the USA gradually between early residential trials 1963 and adoption by the UPC in 1982.  That doesn't help you unfortunately, to know when purple became common for the primer.

Comment: A [2008 patent application](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/c2/d9/6f/e58b8f8f00b512/US20080029213A1.pdf) for invisible primer detectable under UV inspection light, suggests that by 2008 the perils of getting purple goo everywhere were already a widespread problem waiting for a solution. Fast forward 15 years, I guess that solution didn't gain steam. :)    But anyway, I think you cannot rule out the 1990s, and perhaps not the 80s for your pipes.

Comment: I remember purple primer in the mid-1990s when I completely redid the sprinkler system at my house. Didn't do much PVC stuff before then, so not definitive.

Comment: I first saw it used in the 1980's for irrigation piping.

Comment: This question isn't going to help you. The product has been in wide use since the '70s or '80s, but it's only been _required_ in various jurisdictions in more recent decades. There's too much variation in practice. Look for date stamps on the pipe.

Comment: @isherwood is right, look for dates. On the other hand, is there an actual reason to redo the plumbing?